# Error while adding Android platform to Ionic v3.9.2

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic version 3.9.2 with node 5.3.0. I tried to add android platform to my app, but it showing an error as follows:

```
Running command - failed!
ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

   Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output:
   npm ERR! path D:\Ionic\SimBing\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules
   npm ERR! code EPERM
   npm ERR! errno -4048
   npm ERR! syscall lstat
   npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
   'D:\Ionic\SimBing\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules'
   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
   npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
   'D:\Ionic\SimBing\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules'
   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
   \'D:\\Ionic\\SimBing\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\getpass\\node_modules\'\n    at

   Error (native)',
   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
   npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
   npm ERR!   path:
   'D:\\Ionic\\SimBing\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\getpass\\node_modules' }
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!
   C:\Users\eficaz2020\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-12T11_09_42_574Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you should open windows environment variables and add to path **C:\Windows\System32** in system variables, then close and reopen your cmd and try again. Also, be sure to run your commands as administrator.

Check for the version of android provided by cordova under **C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android** (if you are using Windows) and install the respective android platform version.

If all of this doesn't work do the following :

1- remove android platform

2- add the specific version of android that is giving you the error

```
cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```

3- also you can try the command below based on a [similar issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12767)

```
cordova platform add android --nofetch
```